# Table belonging to two models?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I want to have a model for a Baseball team that has many players and statistics about the team.

I also want a model for players that have the same statistics.

How can I have the Statics table belong to both the Baseball Model and the Player Model?

Comment: If by "...the same statistics" you mean you want to duplicate data, then don't do it. The entire point of a relational database is to avoid redundant data. You save the data once and refer to it where necessary. I'm not sure why you think you need to share a statistics table when team data and player data can (and should be) separated.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I meant that they would both want their own entries in the Statistics table.  Like both the Player and the Team would have batting averages, RBIs, Home Runs, etc.

Comment: Sometimes, you think you're asking one question when you're really asking another. Team stats are nothing more than aggregate data from the players who are on that team. Therefore, they can be calculated on the fly via SQL query.  `select sum(homers) from player_stats where team_id = 2 and player_status = "active" ` This query gets you the HR total from whatever team is ID 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Polymorphic association. You can refer [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

Statistic model

```
class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :statisticable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Baseball model

```
class Baseball < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statistic, as: :statisticable
end
```

Player model

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statistic, as: :statisticable
end
```

Your migration file for Statistic model

```
class CreateStatistic < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :statistics do |t|
      t.string  :strength
      t.string  :defensive
      t.string  :attack
      t.references :statisticable, polymorphic: true, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

  end
end
```